# Copying excel visual basic function with static variable to entire column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function increment ()

Static n As Integer

n = n + 1

increment = n

End Function
```

When I copy =increment() to a column, the values that wind up in the column seem random.
I would have expected

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> ...

I get

> 38
>
> 59
>
> 52
>
> ...

Comment: What is the intent of writing this function? FWIW, you can go with built-in `=ROW()` or `=COLUMN()` functions to get similar results.

Comment: I am actually doing something more complex and useful, needing to populate a column with a rather complex function. I boiled it down to the basic issue in order to simplify. The algorithm requires knowledge static variables within the function.

Comment: Your function increments the value of `n` every time Excel recalculates.  That may not happen exactly as you expect (and you should not assume any particular order in your design).

Comment: Precisely as @TimWilliams is mentioning and it will reset once you close the session so you can get absurd results after opening and closing the workbook.

Comment: The only place this function is used is in a single column. When it recalculates, it does not do so from top to bottom of column? I actually don't care about initial value, just that recalculation occurs vertically in column

Comment: So we are saying that static variables are useless in functions that are used in worksheet cells?

Comment: If you need a demo of instability then place this function in two cells A1 and A2 and then go to cell A1 and press F2 and then press enter. The value will get incremented to the next value of static variable.

Comment: I will suggest using an excel name which will provide you better control.

Comment: Static variables are not generally "useless in functions used in worksheet cells" - but in this particular case it seems so. If you could explain your actual use case then someone might have a suggestion for a workaround or modification.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using tcxoFreq(time, r As Range) time referencing another column, and r pulling previous value in working column.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a static variable used in function instantiated in cells of worksheet? Curious how this could work if the calls from the cells are randomly executed.